# Javascript Fetch Requesting API Token through Body

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, api

I am trying to build a frontend using Javascript Fetch to communicate with an API service.

I have to generate a token using the POST method sending apiKey parameter in the Body, and then I have to use the token generated and send it in another POST including date parameters: FechaInicio (StartDate), FechaFinal (currentDate) to retrieve data.

This is how it looks in Postman (Requesting Token):

[image]

Requesting Data (Sending token):
[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
        <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>numeroConsecutivo</th>
                    <th>condicionVenta</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="data">
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script>
        let url = 'https://www.fakeurl.com/webservices/bills.php';//fake
        const apiKey = '+%a4Ur734687631';///fake
        const fechaInicio = "19990101"; //Initial Date
        var fechaFinal = new Date(); //Get current Date, format: 20220416
        var dd = String(fechaFinal.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
        var mm = String(fechaFinal.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
        var yyyy = fechaFinal.getFullYear();
        fechaFinal = yyyy + mm + dd; 

        fetch(url),{
            method: 'POST',
            body: {
                'apiKey': (apiKey) 
            }
            
        .then(response => response.json())//Get Token
        .then(token => displayToken(token))
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
        },

        fetch(url),{
            method: 'POST',
            body: {
                'token': (token), 
                'fechaInicio': (fechaInicio),
                'fechaFinal': (fechaFinal) 
            }
            
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => displayData(data))
            .catch(error => console.log(error)),

            const displayData = (data) => {
            console.log(data)
            let body = ""
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                body += `<tr><td>${data[i].numeroConsecutivo}</td><td>${data[i].condicionVenta}</td></tr>`
            }
            document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = body
            //console.log(body)
            }
        }       
    </script>
```

Any help will be really appreciated!

Comment: your syntax is way off to start with ... it's `fetch(url, { .... options }).then...` ... not `fetch(url), { ... options }.then...` your code won't even run

Comment: but ... if you return the token in the last .then of the first fetch, you can chain the next fetch in a subsequent .then and useit there ... like `fetch(url, {...}.then(r => r.json()).then( token => fetch(url, { body: {token: token ... etc}}).then(r => r.json()).then(data => displayData(data))` ... and so on

Comment: refer to [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) for usage of fetch API

Comment: also ... why are you wrapping your object values in `()` ...

Answer (score 1):

Since your second fetch request depends on the first one, it is better to chain the request - make the second request only after getting the response for the first request.

Then on the success of the second request, we modify the `DOM`. We can also use callbacks, but this is more readable.

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>numeroConsecutivo</th>
        <th>condicionVenta</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="data"></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<script>
  let url = 'https://www.fakeurl.com/webservices/bills.php' //fake
  const apiKey = '+%a4Ur734687631' ///fake
  const fechaInicio = '19990101' //Initial Date
  var fechaFinal = new Date() //Get current Date, format: 20220416
  var dd = String(fechaFinal.getDate()).padStart(2, '0')
  var mm = String(fechaFinal.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0') //January is 0!
  var yyyy = fechaFinal.getFullYear()
  fechaFinal = yyyy + mm + dd
  const displayData = (data) => {
    console.log(data)
    let body = ''
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      body += `<tr><td>${data[i].numeroConsecutivo}</td><td>${data[i].condicionVenta}</td></tr>`
    }
    document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = body
    //console.log(body)
  }

  fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: {
      apiKey: apiKey,
    },
  })
    .then((response) => response.json()) //Get Token
    .then((token) => {
      displayToken(token)
      return fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: {
          token: token,
          fechaInicio: fechaInicio,
          fechaFinal: fechaFinal,
        },
      })
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(displayData)
    .catch((error) => console.log(error))
</script>
```

Comment: so close, yet, there's no need for nested `.then`

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've updated the answer. Can you pls let me know if this is what you suggested?

Comment: yup, that's how I'd do it ... I'd also make `{token: token, fechaInicio: fechaInicio,fechaFinal: fechaFinal,}` shorter in the obvious way